# Bit masking and shifting logic (Java)

Tags: java, bit, masking

I am attempting to reconstruct a UTF-16LE encoded array of bytes back into characters, without using the java API as I will need to do it manually later when I try an implementation of Huffman coding. The code samples I have given are actually in Kotlin but its 99% java so you shouldn't have trouble understanding what it is trying to accomplish - val in this instance is of type char.

This should be reasonably simple, however I believe there is a flaw in my logic and would like to find where my thinking is going wrong.

Ignoring any UNICODE characters that aren't in the Unicode basic multilingual plane, I have the following line of code:

```
 val c = ((((stringBytes[i].toInt()) shl 8) and 0x000000FF) or (stringBytes[i - 1].toInt() and 0x000000FF)).toChar()
```

It works, however I am unsure of it it is correct or not because intuitively I wanted to write it the following way (note the only change is the first masking)

```
 val c = ((((stringBytes[i].toInt()) shl 8) and 0x0000FF00) or (stringBytes[i - 1].toInt() and 0x000000FF)).toChar()
```

This however, comes out incorrect (displays chinese characters, for example) whilst the first line of code given works.

The steps in my mind to combine the bytes of a character within the BMP are to:

- Shift the first (most significant) byte to the left by 8
- AND this with 0x0...FF..00 to zero out all unnecessary bits.
- AND the LSB with 0x0...FF to zero out all unnecessary bits apart from the LSB
- Finally, OR these values together to produce a 2 byte char value.

EDIT: Just realised that the first line of code is only working because only english characters within the BMP have been used and the first byte is usually 0x00 in hex. Meaning that a completely zeroed out byte will always produce the correct result.

Ultimately my question is: Where did my logic in the second example go wrong and why is it producing Chinese characters.

If someone could show me where my thinking is wrong and how I could correct it that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't get what you're doing here:

`((stringBytes[i].toInt()) shl 8) and 0x000000FF)`

If you're doing a left shift and then masking with 0x000000FF, you'll always end up with 0.

Comment: Yeah I realised that and made the edit. However, the code works because the first higher order byte in unicode for english characters is 0 anyway.  The only reason I tried it was because I thought for some reason it was applying the and before the left shift. The second line of code is the one I am more concerned with not working because thats the first way I envisioned doing it correctly.

Comment: `shl`, `or` and `and` makes it look Pascal/Delphi to me instead of Java. And simply concatenating the bits won't work because there are code points for surrogate pair in UTF-16 in which the following code unit must be a valid ending code point. You must exclude those values if you only want characters in the basic plane

Comment: None of the characters I am using atm should extend more than two bytes though, as they are in the basic plane.